# Sqlite3 Python Parameterized Query Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, parameter-passing

I'm getting an error (Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.) for the query:

```
parameterized_query = cur.execute('SELECT courses.dept, courses.course_num, courses.title FROM courses JOIN catalog_index ON catalog_index.course_id = courses.course_id WHERE catalog_index.word IN (?)', arg)
```

where

```
arg = (('computer', 'science', 'economics'),)
```

I am confused because I am passing in a tuple, so I expect this should work, but it is not.

Comment: `arg = ("""'computer', 'science', 'economics'""", )` should do here

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
arg = ('computer', 'science', 'economics')
sql = '''SELECT courses.dept
, courses.course_num
, courses.title 
FROM courses 
JOIN catalog_index 
ON catalog_index.course_id = courses.course_id 
WHERE catalog_index.word IN (?,?,?);'''
parameterized_query = cur.execute(sql, arg)
```

The changes in my suggestion are:

1. Set arg to be a single tuple (it is a nested tuple in your post)
2. Use 3 question marks in the prepared sql statement (it is one question mark in your post).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).